# git push rejected "%commit-sha% was not committed by %programmer-A%"

Tags: git

I have a repository with two main branches, **master** & **develop**. And there are two programmers A & B commits into them. Basically, they commits into "**develop**", and with a stable version, commits would be merged into **master** and pushed to remote.

The problem happened when I pushed local master to remote master after I finished the local merge from develop(local) to master(local):

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags %remotename% master:master     
Pushing to %remote-addr%    
POST git-receive-pack (782 bytes)    
To %remote-addr%    
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (%commit-sha% by %programmer-B% <...> was not committed by %programmer-A% (...))    
error: failed to push some refs to '%remote-addr%'    
Completed with errors, see above
```

Any help would be appricated. Thank you very much.

Comment: can you tell us more about the problem (when it happens, etc) and what the desired outcome is?

Comment: The problem I described in the question happened when I finished local merge from develop into master, and pushed to remote master. The desired outcome should be the success of the push request from local merged master to remote master.

Comment: The "remote rejected" message indicates that a hook on the remote (pre-receive or update hook) said "no".  Since those hooks are programmed by whoever wrote them, you need to consult with the server (the code and/or the author of the hooks) to find out what to do about this.  (The text of the message is a clue, he's comparing "author" and "committer" fields, but there's no hint as to WHY he is doing this.)

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I got it. It shall be the hook problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

Some system admin made a hook on the remote server, it would check the user name and the mail address to be consistent with the user who made the push request.
Since some of the commits I merged were not committed by myself, my push request was rejected.

Comment: this is the reason... so what did you do eventually to resolve it ?

Comment: Just contact the SA to fix the hook script, since this git server is the internal server of the company.